Volume of a cylinder inscribed in an octahedron of edge 1cm
I am trying to find the maximum volume that a cylinder inscribed in an ooctahedron of edge 1 cm can have. Given that the cylinder is on a diagonal of the octahedron. With some calculus and geometry we know that:
The volume of a cylinder is $\pi r^2 h$
In this case $r\leq \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$ and $h\leq \sqrt{2}$
From here I think I should come with an optimization problem but I am missing it.

I think a diagram is needed here to clarify what is meant by a cylinder (3D shape) on the diagonal of an octahedron (2D shape).

@RedFive An octahedron is 3d - Octagon is 2d.

Oops. Yes, you are correct.

Use the fact that the cylinder touches the octahedron face to find a relationship between the $r$ and $h$ of the cylinder. Then you can get an expression of the cylinder volume that uses just one variable, which you can maximise.

Let the diagonal length of octahedron be $d$. Since, edge length is 1, $d$ is $\sqrt{2}$. Consider the cylinder base is distance $x$ away on the diagonal from the closest vertex on octahedron. Then, the height of cylinder is $d - 2x$. The base of cylinder(a circle) is inscribed in a square. Since the diagonal and edge of octahedron are at an angle of 45°, half diagonal of the square(in which cylinder base is inscribed) is equal to $x$. Thus, the radius of inscribed cylinder is $\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}$. The volume of cylinder $V(x) = \frac{\pi}{2} x^2 (\sqrt{2} - 2x)$. By using AM-GM inequality, $x = \sqrt{2} - 2x$ for maximum volume. This implies cylinder height is given by $x = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}$. The radius of cylinder is $\frac{1}{3}$.

How do you get the lenght of the square where the base of the cylinder is inscribed?

It would be nice if you show how you get the square diagonal as $2x$. Although it's just basic trigonometry as one can easily derive the angle from vertices to be $45°$, it would make your answer complete

Edited the answer to explain the square half diagonal is equal to the distance from vertex.
